# Failing to make my navbar (no frameworks/libraries) to stick after scrolling past header

Tags: javascript

I like using JQuery and Bootstrap, but this time I'm trying to design it from scratch. Eveything is working fine except the navbar. 
*Here is the design order*:

**[ upperHeader ]**
**[ navbar ]**
**[ main content...]**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmay8ok0/) => how it looks so far.

I did some research and found a lot of good solutions, but all of them require JQuery. Most went like this:

```
$('#navbar').addClass('fix');
```

Adding and removing a class with css displaying "none" for the upperHeader or setting navbar to `top:0`.

How can I make the navbar stick at the top after I scroll past the upperHeader without using JQuery?

Comment: `#navbar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}`

Comment: you just blew my mind...I didn't know I could set css attributes to classes. Thanks a lot, dude1!

Comment: @richie that `sticky` is in fact a valid value for `position`, not your defined class name. check out [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp)

Comment: I did not know that lol I was used to using `absolute` or `fixed` etc..great tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems in your javascript:

1. `navbar` is `undefined`. When you call `document.getElementById("navbar");`, the HTML DOM is not loaded yet.
2. The part that actually scrolls is `body` instead of `window`.

To solve this two problem, modify your javascript:

```
var navbar;
var sticky;

window.addEventListener("load",function(e){
    navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
    sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
    document.body.addEventListener("scroll",function(e){myFunction()});
});


function myFunction() {
    console.log(document.body.scrollTop,sticky);
  if (document.body.scrollTop >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
    console.log(navbar.className);
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    console.log(navbar.className);
  }
}
```

The last problem is the css:

```
#navbar .sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

`#navbar .sticky` selects element of `class="sticky"` within element of `id="navbar"`. For example, the inner `<div>` of `<div id="navbar"><div class ="sticky"></div></div>`, which does not exist in your page.

You want `#navbar.sticky` (remove the space in between) that is the element of `id="navbar" class="sticky"`, which selects `<div id="navbar" class="sticky"></div>`.

Of course you can just simply use [position:sticky](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp) without messing around with javascript.

Comment: Great answer, my friend. I followed your instructions and everything works. I decided to just remove my javascript altogether since I can achieve  the same result just by using position: sticky.